# How to add annotations/cards/end screens to a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-studio, annotations

I'm studying a lot of tutorials out there, but none of them show the current YouTube interface, which looks like YouTube removed the option to insert those text annotations into the video.
Could anyone tell me how to insert texts in YouTube videos in the current interface (2019)?

---

### Edit 1

Here when I go to [Video manager](https://www.youtube.com/my_videos):
[image]

Here when clicking on the "Options":
[image]

There is no "Edit", only "Edit Title and Description"

Answer (score 1):

**`Cards` and `End Screens` you can only add to your own uploaded videos** are replacing annotations since YouTube gradually retires and deletes all them all, even from older videos.

### How to add cards or end screens to your YouTube video.

- **Go to your [Video manager](https://www.youtube.com/my_videos)**
- **Find the video that you want to add cards to and select `EDIT`**.
- **Go to `Video elements`**

[image: YouTube Video elements]

- **Select `Add an end screen`** and choose from the types provided.

[image: YouTube end screens]

- **OR select `Add cards`** and choose from the types provided.

[image: YouTube video cards]

You can find more info at:

- [Lesson: Let cards and end screens do the work](https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/page/lesson/cards)
- [Add end screens to videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6388789)
- [Add cards to videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but you've edited my original question and made it broader than it originally was, to adapt it to your answer, and at the same time you didn't answer my original question. 
1) I'm asking how to insert annotation (text blocks) in youtube during its execution
2) The "Video Manager" link you provided shows me a list of my videos, but there is no "edit" option for the video like you said
3) Maybe if you put some screenshots for your first steps, it would be more comprehensible

Comment: _"...you've edited my original question...to adapt it to your answer, and at the same time you didn't answer my original question."_ It is not broader. It is updated for 2019 and _"the current YouTube interface"_ as you asked. _"I'm asking how to insert annotation (text blocks) in youtube during its execution"_ You can **not**. You used to but not any more. As I mention _"`Cards` and `End Screens` ...are replacing annotations"_ Also there **is** an edit link because they are **your** videos. Of course you can edit **your** videos. Finally, please have a look at the provided links for more info

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I inserted some images in the original question to show you what I get, could you please show me what's wrong?

Comment: Try first selecting the video and click on the Edit button right over it on the black stripe presented. I'll post you a screenshot as well.

Comment: Sorry. Scratch that. Select and go to the far right on `EDIT DRAFT` and click. This will get you to the screens I have uploaded in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any `EDIT DRAFT` option after selecting the video (when the black stripe appears). Could you send a screenshot?

Comment: Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14BT9.png)

Comment: Found it?. If not lets take it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101754/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-marikamitsos).